# Getting Data from MySql server using Php scripts in UWP apps

Tags: php, mysql, json, database, uwp

Iam having a PHP script like

```
<?php
try{
$con= new PDO('mysql:host=iamhost;dbname=android_welcome', 'android_test', '**********') ;
$con->exec('SET NAMES utf8');
}  
 catch(Exeption $e){
  die('Error:'.$e->getMessage());
  }
  ?>
```

the above one is Connect.Php script, How can i connect to DB using this script and get executed my remaining scripts on Server and get JSON data to my UWP application.

I haven't installed any tools except Visual Studio Community 2015 Updt 2 on my PC, Should i have to install any other tools please guide me, Iam new to use MySQL Server and PHP scripts in UWP Applications.

Help me out.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Did you install a MYSQL Server instance?

Comment: Or should you be trying to connect to an SQL Server instance?

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: Hello, @RiggsFolly , Iam just starting the UWP apps with PHP Scripts , and those scripts used for same app in android, i wanted to know how to use them in UWP apps, and what are the tools required for doing so.

Comment: I am guessing a bit, but I would say you probably need a web server and a database installed as well. Are you intending to use IIS or Apache and MySQL

Comment: we are using MySQL. it is already used for Android app, the same i have to use for UWP app.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get data in UWP - you should create REST API. You can do it with PHP. Try to search information about how to do it (it's much more then some lines of code).

There is also possibility to connect UWP directly to MySQL database with help of [Connector/Net](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.9.html)
You can install it and add reference to MySql.Data.RT.dll

Here is a little snippet how to create table and add row:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
```

........

```
using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("Database=as_bfb6f501597b777;Data Source=us-cdbr-azure-west-c.cloudapp.net;User Id=b74038821f5aea;Password=2564f4e5;SslMode=None;"))
{
connection.Open();

MySqlCommand createCommand = new MySqlCommand("CREATE TABLE demotable(salary int,surname varchar(255))", connection);

createCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

MySqlCommand addCommand = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO demotable (salary,surname) VALUES (5000,'Smith')", connection);

addCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```